# How to remove temporary files after reboot on Windows?

Tags: windows, temporary-files

Ubuntu deletes temporary files by default after reboot, but Windows doesn't. How to make Windows to do the same?

Comment: IE temp files or windows temp files? ( %temp%  folder)

Comment: %TEMP% (c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp)

Comment: Linux has two temporary folders: */tmp* gets wiped at reboot, */var/tmp* doesn't. In Windows, it's harder to decide which files can be deleted safely. I have seen applications that even stored their executable in the temporary folder (a driver, IIRC, and no, it wasn't malware). Deleting only temporary files that haven't been accessed for X days would probably be a better approach.

Comment: Why would one do it at every startup? That's a waste of time. Plan to do such cleanup once a week or month.

Comment: You may run into trouble deleting files with the extension "etiqls" ("sqlite" backwards) since they are usually kept in that folder and are locked. They are used by anti-virus and some other software, and are fine to skip.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Instead of going through the trouble (and **danger**) of doing this manually, I would recommend a program like [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/builds) which can automate this process and leaves alone files that were created within the last 24 hours.

This is quite important, since some programs that might also run on startup could already be using temporary files, potentially causing issues. On Linux, the [`/tmp` directory](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/tmp.html) is known to be cleared out on every reboot, and all Linux programs are therefore designed around that principle.

Here's how to make CCleaner start with Windows:
[image: CCleaner options]

Make sure **only** "Temporary Files" and **other things you really want to clear on every startup** are checked:
[image: CCleaner selection]

CCleaner should only delete files over a day old by default, but it doesn't hurt to check this setting:
[image: CCleaner advanced options]

After all this is done, CCleaner should run quietly in the notification area at every startup. The icon will disappear when cleaning is complete.
[image: CCleaner tray icon]

Comment: CCleaner was infected once. That's one reason it's always better to use builtin functions, than installing 3rd party apps for such a trivial task.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think there's an option for that. You can create a `.bat` file to delete the temporary files and make it run on startup (when Windows starts). The following should work:

Delete all files in %temp% but leave the folders untouched:

```
@echo off
del /s /f /q "%temp%/*.*"
```

Delete everything on %temp%:

```
@echo off
rmdir /s /q %temp%
md %temp%
```

Delete all `.tmp` files:

```
@echo off
del /s /f /q "%temp%/*.tmp"
```

Be aware that some programs use files in `%temp%` to run so do this at your own risk.

To make the `.bat` run on startup follow [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-vista/run-a-program-automatically-when-windows-starts) tutorial from Microsoft or one of the many others online...

Answer (score 8):

As a matter of fact, it is a waste of processor time to perform such a cleanup every startup.

Instead, add a scheduled task, triggered once a week to execute a batch located in the same directory of [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner), containing:

```
ccleaner /AUTO
```

This will perform a scan and automatic cleanup without any prompts to all boxes ticked on ccleaner and WILL include user-specified directories. (does not perform registry fixes)

extra tip: on batch properties, you may even select it to run minimized, so it bothers you less on the startup; the scan will be rather quick and probably you wont even notice the minimized window.

Comment: Is there some evidence that this is a factual matter? o.O

Answer (score 4):

[image: cleanmgr]

You can use the builtin Windows function to cleanup all temporary files (and much more).

Just once, run

```
CLEANMGR /sageset
```

Now select anything you want to clean up.

Now by running

```
CLEANMGR /sagerun
```

it will exactly run all cleanup jobs as selected.

See more in the [Microsoft Knowledgebase](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315246/how-to-automate-the-disk-cleanup-tool-in-windows-xp-and-windows-7).

Answer (score 3):

My batch file to remove temporary files older than a day

```
IF EXIST %TEMP% ( FORFILES /P %TEMP% /D -01 /C "cmd /c IF @isdir==TRUE (rd /s /q @path) else (del /q @path)" )
```

Comment: There has been no DOS for a long time

Comment: @davidbaumann Not sure what you are trying to say. It's Windows Batch, not DOS Batch. It's a perfectly viable solution for every version of Windows up to and including Windows 10.