# CCleaner doesn't include username\AppData\Local\Temp for cleaning

Tags: cleaning, temporary-files, ccleaner

Does anyone know why CCleaner doesn't include username\AppData\Local\Temp for cleaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why doesn't CCleaner include `username\AppData\Local\Temp` for cleaning?

Only CCleaner will be able to answer that question.

However you can configure CCleaner to include that directory (and any others you wish to scan.

- Click "Options" > "Include" > "Add"

  [image]
- Click "Browse", select your temp directory, then click "OK"

  [image]

Comment: Thanks. I see a similar post here as well: https://superuser.com/questions/571901/is-it-safe-to-delete-appdata-local-temp/902645